# UWP call method in main page

Tags: class, methods, uwp

wondering if someone can help me out here?

I have a method in my class DB called grab entries. I want to call this method from my main page every time it opens. How would I go about this? DB.Grab_Entries isn't an option. Neither is refresh, which would need to be called before it. Am I missing something painfully obvious here?

DB class

```
namespace TestApp2
{
    public static class DB
    {
        private static SuspendingEventHandler App_Suspending;

        public static void database()
        {
            Application.Current.Suspending += new SuspendingEventHandler(App_Suspending);
            using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=sqliteSample.db"))
            {
                //Creation of the database table
                db.Open();
                String tableCommand1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EmployeeTable (Employee_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, First_Name NVARCHAR(20) NULL, Last_Name NVARCHAR(40) NULL, Address NVARCHAR(50) NULL , Position NVARCHAR(20) NULL, Pay_Rate DOUBLE NULL, Tax_Code NVARCHAR(10) NULL, Sex NVARCHAR(20), NI NVACHAR(10), Emergency_Details NVARCHAR(100)";
                
                SqliteCommand createTable = new SqliteCommand(tableCommand1, db);
                
                try
                {
                    createTable.ExecuteReader();
                }
                catch (SqliteException)
                {
                    //Do nothing
                }
            }
        }

        private static List<Person> Grab_Entries()
        {
            List<Person> entries = new List<Person>();
            using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=sqliteSample.db"))
            {
                db.Open();
                SqliteCommand selectCommand = new SqliteCommand("SELECT * from EmployeeTable", db);
                SqliteDataReader query;
                try
                {
                    query = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                }
                catch (SqliteException)
                {
                    //Handle error
                    return entries;
                }
                while (query.Read())
                {
                    //entries.Add(query.GetString(0));

                }
                db.Close();
            }
            return entries;

        }
    }
}
```

MainPage class

```
namespace TestApp2
{
    

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        
        List<Person> persons;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            persons = new List<Person>();

        
        }

        private async void searchEmployee_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await new MessageDialog("Test").ShowAsync();

        }

        private void rota_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Rota));
        }

        private void emailEmployee_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(email));
        }

        private void addEmployee_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AddEmployee));
        }

        public void EmployeeGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            **TODO HERE**
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Grab_Entries of DB you set is **private**, the DB.Grab_Entries can't work. You could change the Grab_Entries method and Person class as public, then you can use `DB.Grab_Entries` to get the data.

If you still want to keep the private status, you could try to find the method by using GetMethod and then specify to include non-public and static members in the search. After that, invoke the method. For example:

```
using System.Reflection;
public void EmployeeGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Person> MyLists = (typeof(DB).GetMethod("Grab_Entries", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).Invoke(null, null)) as List<Person>;
}
```

Comment: Ah! perfect! yup, access modifiers and lack of sleep haha!! thank you so much!